# Highlighting selected geojson feature and return to previous state when another one is selected using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, features, markers

I've a map with a geojson layer containing markers, polygons and lines.

I made a module so that when a feature is clicked, its properties are displayed in a frame and not in standard Leaflet popup. It works perfectly well and I'm quite happy with it.

Point is that I'd like to have the selected feature to highlight when clicked and return to unselected state when another one is clicked.

Do you have an idea on how I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 4):

It's easy have two styles, I had a green for my stateLayer and created a Highlight layer, then in the onEachFeature function create a layer on-click function.

```
        layer.on("click", function (e) { 
            stateLayer.setStyle(style); //resets layer colors
            layer.setStyle(highlight);  //highlights selected.
        });
```

working example, right click view source.  http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/basic/basic_Poly.html

Comment: Thanks you Bill ! And how do you do if I have feature AND marker ?

Comment: By feature you mean marker, polyline, polygon right? My example works on polylines or polygons or circlemarkers. For markers I usually just put a small circlemarker under them. Here is an example of my yellow select on a marker. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Simple/indexMap3.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Do you have an example that included all kind of features ? Thanks you for your help btw

Comment: Here is a page of examples I used for a class.I have examples of circlemarkers, polylines and polygons here, right clck on the example, view source to see how I did it. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/ The style and getColor functions are similar for all except regular markers, which don't change unless you do fontawesome markers.

Comment: Thanks Bill, That is very interesting. I'll have a look at it

Comment: Check out https://www.extension.iastate.edu/communities/gis/quicktasksheets  search on Leaflet, The have task sheets that may help, For circleMarkers: https://indicator.extension.iastate.edu/projects/tasksheets/reports/PM2082-15h.pdf.  That should help get you started.

Comment: Thank you bill. Actually, instead of circle markers, I'm using svg